# Class not found..java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have been through many posts but none of those helped! I am getting the following error while running JUnit tests for a test class:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.project.abc.pqr.AbcTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Its running the tests through console but since I want to debug the tests, I need to do that through Eclipse. Can you pleas suggest what can I do?

[image]

[image]

I tried:

> Build Again
>
> Disable Maven Nature and then Enable Maven Nature
>
> Maven Update Project
>
> mvn eclipse:eclipse
>
> mvn eclipse:clean
>
> Added this to .project file

```
 <buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
 </buildSpec>
 <natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
 </natures>
```

EDIT:
Added Run Configuration for the test class:
[image]

[image]

.classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" 
 path="src/test/java">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" 
path="src/main/resources">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="con" 
path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui. 
launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="GROOVY_DSL_SUPPORT">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

I want to add the packaging in my pom is jar. 
    jar

Comment: Why's it looking for a type with ".java" as part of its fully qualified name?

Comment: Hi @nitind Edited it. Just for sake of asking this question without exposing my class nae I added .java manually.

Comment: What's the launch config for your test look like? Is it running a test class, and individual method, or the whole project? Is there a corresponding class file on disk for the test class?

Comment: @nitind What's the launch config for your test look like? ->Added Run Config screenshots. Is it running a test class, and individual method, or the whole project? I am running the test class. Is there a corresponding class file on disk for the test class? I dont see any class file related to my test class. I checked in target and bin.

Comment: What's the .classpath file look like? You actually need to compile your classes.

Comment: Added my .classpath file. I ran 'mvn compile' , 'mvn package' , 'mvn clean' and 'mvn install' through console but I didnt see any .class file for tests. Though I can see .class files for the src/main files.

Comment: I suggest you to create new maven project and copy all files and try again. It should work